# Relation of Executors and Bolts in Storm Stream API

Tags: java, distributed-computing, apache-storm, stream-processing

I have a complex storm query that is written in Storms Stream API and consists out of multiple operations, like `map`, `filter`, `window` and so on.

When I run this topology on my remote cluster, I am just able to see that several executors are executed on my machines, but in the Storm UI there appearing far *less bolts than operators (=bolts)* I have implemented before. I set the task parallelism to 1, also the num of tasks per operator to 1.

Example: For a query running with a `source`, 2 x `map`, a `sink`, there is just one `spout` and one `bolt` displayed.

So my questions are:

**Is there any chaining / co-locating of operators happening in storm?
How could I sepereate each operator from the Streaming API to one worker machine?**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the log files of operators. Print something in each bolt and spout and see how they react in the logs.
Besides, there are some tags in storm conf like `topology.ras.one.component.per.worker: true`, `topology.ras.one.executor.per.worker: true` and `topology.ras.acker.executors.per.worker: 1`  that may work for you.

Comment: Well, printing will show me that there i some co-locating, but how could I separate?

The `ras`-Configs are for Storms `Resource Aware Scheduler` that I would pefer not to use.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm not sure exactly what happens. However, I think the only way to find out what's going on is to check the logs, nimbus and scheduler.